# HTML - prevent auto-fill or auto-completion of fields (FF, IE, IPad)

Tags: html, ipad, security, internet-explorer, firefox

in Firefox-preferences you can select if passwords should be stored and if fields should be auto-filled. If I visit the site of my bank I wondered how it is handled that I won't be asked if I want to store password or username!?

Which markup is necessary to prevent auto-fill or auto-complete in webforms? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Doesn't work on ff3 though, as far as I remember

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Comment: I am using Java Server Faces so I tried to add autocomplete-attribute via JQuery: jQuery('#form_username').attr('autocomplete', 'off'); Unfortunately no effect.

Comment: how about `jQuery('#form_username').prop('autocomplete', 'off')` ?

Comment: @Jochen, the code you mention in your comment works for me, tested on FF 12 and IE 9. Which browser(s) did you test it on? How does the DOM look like if you inspect the form element?

Comment: DOM is okay - there is an attribute autocomplete and the value is off. It seems like now I have to dig deeper in my firefox preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this bit for a different point of view. Why not honeypot it stop chrome from botting your fields. It appears to work cross browser for me. Worth a shot.

http://benjaminjshore.info/2014/05/chrome-auto-fill-honey-pot-hack.html